# Getting Last Logon from all DCs, PowerShell slow compared to AD Tidy

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I get the last logon dates of all PCs in my domain using AD Tidy - it takes roughly 15 minutes and it shows me the last Logon Date and the Last Logon DC.

If I do the same with a powershell script, it is horribly slow.

```
Foreach Client (3000~ in total)
    Foreach DC (35)
        Get last logon time of client on DC
```

It takes about 2 seconds to check one DC for one client. So about 70 Seconds per client times 3000 is about 58hours, which is kind of accurate for the time it is taking.

Do you guys have any idea how they do it in 15 minutes? Or why PS is so slow?

Tbf I didn't control their results yet, so might be they just take the first available DC, but I doubt it.

Comment: Umm... you're querying each client on each DC *sequentially*, and you're wondering why that is slow? Query each DC for *all* clients, and you'll likely see a significant performance boost. Do the 35 queries in parallel, and the performance will improve even more.

Comment: Query each DC for all users _once_ (potentially in parallel), then find the newest timestamps afterwards

Comment: Heh. Great minds think alike. ;)

Comment: lol, this ain't the first time @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes I think that might be it. I will work with the Jobs in powershell and check how to query them parallel. Thank you! Since you were the first to reply, would you make it an answer?

Comment: @MathiasR.JessenThank you Mathias, I think this should boost it immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching information from Active Directory, running one query per object at a time is going to take significantly longer than querying all relevant objects at once. What you want to do is get the `lastLogon` attribute for all computers from each domain controller.

```
$lastLogons = $controllers | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property LastLogonDate -Server $_
} | Select-Object DNSHostName, LastLogonDate -Unique
```

That alone should speed up processing time notably.

To further improve performance you could run the queries to the DCs in parallel rather than sequentially. There are several ways to do this, but personally I feel most comfortable with [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx).

```
$jobs = foreach ($dc in $controllers) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property LastLogonDate -Server $using:dc
    }
}

$lastLogons = $jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job |
              Select-Object DNSHostName, LastLogonDate -Unique

$jobs | Remove-Job
```